# Difference between orthogonal projection onto a point and onto a vector.

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

A trivial question although I'd like some good answers.
Are there any mathematical difference?
My vector calculus is a bit rusty.

Comment: There no such thing as orthogonal projection onto a point. What on the point is the projection supposed to be "orthogonal" to? Perhaps you meant orthogonal projection of a point onto something else (say a line or a plane)?

Comment: I agree. Orthogonality is always a relation between 2 planes or at least between two vectors.  My notes mentioned "orthogonal to a point....".
It could be poor wording. But your post has sort of cleared the confusion.